# WPF Trigger when property value is greater than a certain amount

Tags: wpf, triggers

I want to do something like this:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Width" Value=">25">
       <!-- Set values here -->
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Anyway to do something like this?

Answer (score 39):

You can use a data trigger and set the binding RelativeSource to Self. Data Triggers allow binding and bindings lets you have converters.

Example:

```
   <Button Content="I change colour depending on my width for some reason">
        <Button.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger
                Binding="{Binding
                Path=Width,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                Converter={StaticResource isLessThanConverter},
                ConverterParameter=50}"
                Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="Red" />
            <DataTrigger>
        <Button.Triggers>
    <Button>
```

[Reference](http://shortfastcode.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-do-you-use-converter-on-trigger.html)

Comment: +1 for pointing out the isLessThanConverter approach with ConverterParameter.

Comment: In the Binding, `ActualWidth` should be used instead because the `Width` property is `NaN` if not set explicitly.

Comment: I get a runtime exception _Triggers collection members must be of type EventTrigger_. It only works when wrapped in a style or template triggers.

Answer (score 6):

Not without code behind. Usual practice is:

- When working with UI elements, create an IValueConverter and bind to the property using the converter.
- When working with bound data, create a bool property on your data and trigger from that property.

Comment: I like the idea of using a converter even with bound data. When using the MVVM pattern it helps keep view code out of the viewmodel.

Answer (score 2):

Something might have been added in SP1, but the way I've achieved this in the past is with a ValueConvertor that converts the value into a boolean.

In your example your convertor would return true if the value was > 25, false otherwise. If that doesn't make sense I can put an example up :-)

Answer (score 0):

Data Trigger only validates exact value, not validates "evaluated values"(like greater than, less than, addition etc.). you need a converter to convert to exact value.