# Is it possible to set a data trigger when it is not a value?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger

I have a check box that I want to collapse when a value is any value except one.

So I would like to do something like:

```
<CheckBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ucPrincipal, Path=DataContext.MyProperyViewMode}" Value<>"MyValue">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</CheckBox.Style>
```

Of course, the value in the data trigger can't use the `<>` comparer, but that's the idea. `MyPropertyViewModel` is a value of an enumeration.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886988/wpf-trigger-that-would-work-if-the-value-is-equal-or-greater

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have only one value when it should be visible you can simply invert your condition. By default set `Visibility` to `Collapsed` and only when it's that value trigger `Visible`

```xml
<CheckBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ucPrincipal, Path=DataContext.MyProperyViewMode}" Value="MyValue">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</CheckBox.Style>
```

Comment: I am trying this solution, but I set MyProperyViewMode in my view model constructor, and the data trigger seems that it is not fired. Could the reason be because I use another view model to create this view model, create the view and realation both of them?

Comment: It works, I don't notice that you set the the visibility insede the style and I did it on the properties of the check box. This works fine. Thank so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `IValueConverter`. Suppose that your implementation is called `YourConverter`.

This is the `Convert` method:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
        YourEnum enumValue = (YourEnum)value;
        return enumValue == YourEnum.WrongValue;
}
```

So your DataTrigger will be:

```
<CheckBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ucPrincipal, Path=DataContext.MyProperyViewMode, Converter={StaticResource YourConverter}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</CheckBox.Style>
```

Of course you have to declare the converter as a resource.

Comment: In this case because it's a simple data trigger I would like to avoid the need of the converter. But it's a possible solution too. Thanks.