# DataTrigger When Greater Than a Number

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I have a value that is caled `OperativeCount`. I would like the colour of the `DataGridColumn` to change when this number is greater than 10. Something similar to this;

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DGCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding OperativeCount}" Value=">10">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Obviously for now the `Value=">10"` is not working but essentially that is what I would like to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF Trigger that would work if the value is equal or greater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886988/wpf-trigger-that-would-work-if-the-value-is-equal-or-greater)

Answer (score 4):

Blend SDK for WPF can get it done very quickly without any code behind. Check out [DataTrigger (Blend SDK for WPF)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn195685%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Use ChangePropertyAction as the behavior.

```
<ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding OperativeCount}" Comparison="GreaterThan" Value="10">
  <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="FontWeight" >
     <ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
       <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
     </ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
   </ei:ChangePropertyAction>
</ei:DataTrigger>
```

Don't bother much, let Blend take care of it.

Comment: It was very hard for me to find the software, so here is the most relevant links to the moment:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5915
and
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801
.Please find some new (but unclear!) information from the "overview" linked in the first URL as well!

Comment: You are referring to the older version of Expression Studio. The Expression Studio is now retired and Expression Blend has been included in Visual Studio. Just get the community edition of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to reuse this component or make it "general", a simpler and most focused solution can be the following.

Create a converter with this code:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class CountToFontWeightConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

            var count = (int)value;

            if (count > 10)
                return FontWeights.Bold;
            else
                return FontWeights.Normal;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it this way:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>

  <local:CountToFontWeightConverter x:Key="CountToFontWeightConverter"/>

  <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" x:Key="DGCellStyle">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight"
            Value="{Binding OperativeCount,
              Converter={StaticResource CountToFontWeightConverter}}"/>
  </Style>

</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Obviously, if the `OperativeCount` property changes during your app's lifetime, it must raise notifications on change, via `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation, or via `Reactive` library.

You can generalize a little bit this solution by passing the limit of `10` as a parameter for the converter, instead of hard-coding it inside the converter itself, so you can use it in several places with different limit.