# WPF Datagrid with similar Outlook 2013 mail list style

Tags: wpf, styles, datatemplate

I am new to WPF. I want to design a Datagrid similar to mail list in outlook 2013 having same style and features.

In outlook 2013, Datagrid template changes when its width decreases and goes to one liner type of mode when it expands.

I tried to implement this behavior with two separate Datagrid controls (only one control will be visible at a time), however, I faced lot of issues. Changes occurred in one grid have to reflect on other grid. I think its an indirect method. Can I achieve this by using single control.

Comment: Can you show your codes?

Comment: I am glad you've found the answer useful. Keep us updated here if you have more difficulties. You can add a **Update** line under your question and add extra info anytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you are familiar with `Triggers`, however I would suggest you to apply a `Trigger` to your `Style` based on the control's `width` property and change it's style the way you wish to be.

Here is a very good tutorial about `Templates` and `Triggers` from Josh Smith that you can learn from. In fact, have a look at all the parts of this tutorial if you want to learn more about WPF best practices.

[A Guided Tour of WPF – Part 4 (Data templates and triggers)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18303/A-Guided-Tour-of-WPF-Part-Data-templates-and-tri)

Meanwhile since you're looking for a `Trigger` value to be a range rather than a certain value, say (Pseudo) `Trigger when ListView's width < 300`, you will need to use a custom converter with your trigger.

For an example of such converter look into this question

[WPF Trigger when property value is greater than a certain amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094401/wpf-trigger-when-property-value-is-greater-than-a-certain-amount)