# Storing information in ViewModel or using IValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, ivalueconverter

If I want to change the `Background`-color of a `Button` in wpf to red, if the property `Amount` in my view model is `0` and to green if it is greater than 0, is it better to use a value converter for this, or should I simply implement a custom `Background`-property in my view model? This `Background`-property would wrap the `Amount`-value to a `SolidColorBrush`, which will be bound to the `Background` of the `Button`.

Which way is more straight forward?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a `DataTrigger`.

Apply the following style to your button.

It has a binding to the `Amount` property in your view model.
It sets the default background color to 'green' and changes to 'red' if the value of `Amount` is 0.

```
<Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Amount}" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

**Additional info**

You can also check for more than one codition using a `MultiDataTrigger`.

It looks like this:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{...}, Value="..."/>
        <Condition Binding="{...}, Value="..."/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
        <Setter Property="A" Value="..."/>
        <Setter Property="B" Value="..."/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

Check out [this article](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/multi-triggers-multitrigger-multidatatrigger/) on how to use it.

It seems that for range checking you would need to implement a `IValueConverter` like mentioned in the other responses or in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094401/wpf-trigger-when-property-value-is-greater-than-a-certain-amount).

Comment: Will it be set to green back, if the condition for red is false?

Comment: I just tested it, seems to work. I have the button which shall change the color and I use two more buttons to set the Amount property in the view model to 0 or 5 (just something else then 0) and I can see the button change its background color accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it with Trigger, but Converter is Ok too. But I definitely won't make property Background in ViewModel, because Background is about design, about view so it is better to define it in View

Answer (score 2):

I'd make `bool` property in viewmodel, which is calculated when `Amount` is changed:

```
public bool IsAmountZero
{
    get { return Amount == 0; }
}

private int _amount;
public int Amount
{
    get { return _amount; }
    set
    {
        _amount = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsAmountZero));
    }
}
```

And then write converter `BoolToColorConverter` (where colors could be via `ConverterParameter` somehow).

```
// in current form it's actually BoolToColorRedGreenConverter
public class BoolToColorConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public BoolToColorConverter() { }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
        {
            var colorFalse = Colors.Green;
            var colorTrue = Colors.Red;
            if (parameter != null)
            {
                //...
            }
            return (bool)value ? colorTrue : colorFalse;
        }
        throw new InvalidCastException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

use it like this

```
    <Button.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding IsAmountZero, Converter={local:BoolToColorConverter}}" />
    </Button.Background>
```

This would be quite reusable solution.

Otherwise just make converter `IntZeroCheckToColorGreenRedConverter`, but it will not be very reusable compared to one with `bool` property.

Idea with `Brush` property in view model is bad, because viewmodel doesn't realy care about colors. Viewmodel should only contain logic related to model which is then used by view. If you want to simply change color (e.g use `Blue` instead of `Green`) - this change has to be done in the view. Therefore `bool` property and `BoolToColorConverter` (or `BoolToSolidBrushConverter` to use directly with `Background` attribute in xaml) converters.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `Button`'s `background` is something view's related i don't thing that setting it from the ViewModel is a good idea, i think that it is much better if you define the `Amount` property in the ViewModel, define a `DataTrigger` to check the `amount` value Against the **0** using a **Converter**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <YurNs:GreaterThanValConverter x:Key="GreaterThanValConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Amount,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <Button Content="Button">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Amount,Converter={StaticResource GreaterThanValConverter}}" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>      
</StackPanel>
```

and the converter

```
 public  class GreaterThanValConverter:IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int) value > 0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

One more thing you may as well consider passing a parameter to the converter to compare against so that your solution would be as customizable as possible.